# rest calls not return correctly with curl

Tags: java, jersey

I have the following snippet(Jersey Rest 1.9 Tomcat 7):

```
 import javax.ws.rs.GET;...
  // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String plainTextOutput() {...

  // This method is called if XML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML) ...
  public String xmlOutput() {...
```

When called with curl as follows:

- curl url
- -H "Content-Type:text/xml"
- -H "Content-Type:application/xml

They all return values for plainText.

However, adding the following:

```
  //above not working
  // This method is called if XML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
   public String xml2Output() {...
```

all curl commandline return xml2Output, regardless of content type, including text/plain

Do I need server configuration change? Curl command not correct?

Comment: you need to use the `Accept` header in your request

Comment: Thank you so much! I am not posting data, just getting.

Comment: Let me know if my answer solves your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use the `Accept` header for content negotation

HTTP has the concept of *content negotation*, that is, it allows us to provide different representations of a resource at the same URI. The user agents can specify which representation fit their capabilities the best. The [`Accept`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2) header is used in the request to indicate the media type that is acceptable by the client.

To address your issue, remove the [`Content-Type`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5) header (that indicates the media type of the payload) from the request and then add the [`Accept`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2) header to the request, indicating the media type that must be sent in the response.

Have a look at what the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231), the current reference for the HTTP protocol, says about these headers:

> [**5.3.2.  Accept**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2)
>
> The `Accept` header field can be used by user agents to specify
> response media types that are acceptable. [...]

> [**3.1.1.5.  Content-Type**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5)
>
> The `Content-Type` header field indicates the media type of the
> associated representation: either the representation enclosed in the
> message payload or the selected representation, as determined by the
> message semantics. [...]

### Matching JAX-RS annotations with HTTP headers

There a couple of things to keep in mind regarding how the JAX-RS runtime matches the HTTP headers with the annotation:

- The value of the [`Accept`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2) header will be matched with the value of the [`@Produces`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Produces.html) annotation.
- The value of the [`Content-Type`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5) header will be matched with the value of the [`@Consumes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Consumes.html) annotation.

For more details, check the [Jersey documentation about resources](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html).

In your situation, we have the following:

- For `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)`, use the `Accept` header with the value `application/xml`.
- For `@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)`, use the `Accept` header with the value `text/xml`.
- For `@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)`, use the `Accept` header with the value `text/plain`.